# Android pass multiple data from list to another activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, onitemclicklistener, onitemlongclicklistener

I have got:

```
mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        choosedOffer= mListTest1.get(position).toString();
        return false;
    }
});
```

and

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListviewActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("text",choosedOffer);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

in one activity.

The second activity contains:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                String passedText=data.getStringExtra("text");
                ar.add(passedText);
            }
        }

}
```

**Now what I need:**

After long click on `mListView` item, I want to store its position somehow and then, after button `"Back"` click, I want the position to be passed to `ar` array in second activity. It works but only for one item from list. If I click another position and then `"Back"` button, only the last clicked item position will be passed to another activity. Can I pass somehow all items/positions that were clicked before pressing `"Back"` button (not only the last one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> choosedOffer = new ArrayList<String>();

mListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        choosedOffer.add(mListTest1.get(position).toString());
        return false;
    }
});
```

and

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(ListviewActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("text",choosedOffer);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

The second activity

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            ArrayList<String> passedText = data.getStringArrayListExtra("text");
            ar.addAll(passedText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great! Gotta practice Arrays :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can store your `long press` positions into an `ArrayList<Integer>`. Pass that to your `Intent` using `i.putIntegerArrayListExtra(name, value)`. In your receiving `Activity` use `data.getIntegerArrayListExtra(name)` to get the values.